# simplify code with function in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have trouble to simplify the code in AJAX.
I use AJAX like below, and it's work perfectly, but the code looks dirty.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/indexMajorNewsGroup.json",
    dataType:'json',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    ifModified: true,
    success: function getData(result){

             // =======other function=======

            if(window.innerWidth>1280) {
                textEllipsis('.biggestNews .majorNews h2',0,30);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news2 h2',1,30);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news3 h2',2,30);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news4 h2',3,30);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news5 h2',4,30);
            }else if(window.innerWidth>980 && window.innerWidth<1280){
                textEllipsis('.biggestNews .majorNews h2',0,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news2 h2',1,10);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news3 h2',2,10);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news4 h2',3,10);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news5 h2',4,10);
            }else{
                //mb
                textEllipsis('#newsMb1 h2',0,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news2 h2',1,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news3 h2',2,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news4 h2',3,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news5 h2',4,15);
                textEllipsis('#newsMb2 h2',5,15);
            }

           // =======other function=======

           function NewsSlideRule(){

              // =======other function=======

              if(window.innerWidth>1280) {
                textEllipsis('.biggestNews .majorNews h2',0,30);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news2 h2',1,30);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news3 h2',2,30);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news4 h2',3,30);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news5 h2',4,30);
            }else if(window.innerWidth>980 && window.innerWidth<1280){
                textEllipsis('.biggestNews .majorNews h2',0,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news2 h2',1,10);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news3 h2',2,10);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news4 h2',3,10);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news5 h2',4,10);
            }else{
                //mb
                textEllipsis('#newsMb1 h2',0,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news2 h2',1,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news3 h2',2,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news4 h2',3,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news5 h2',4,15);
                textEllipsis('#newsMb2 h2',0,15);
            }
         }

    }
```

I try to put `if` in function, like this：

```
function RWDtextEllipsis(){

            if(window.innerWidth>1280) {
                textEllipsis('.biggestNews .majorNews h2',0,30);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news2 h2',1,30);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news3 h2',2,30);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news4 h2',3,30);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news5 h2',4,30);
            }else if(window.innerWidth>980 && window.innerWidth<1280){
                textEllipsis('.biggestNews .majorNews h2',0,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news2 h2',1,10);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news3 h2',2,10);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news4 h2',3,10);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news5 h2',4,10);
            }else{
                //mb
                textEllipsis('#newsMb1 h2',0,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news2 h2',1,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news3 h2',2,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news4 h2',3,15);
                textEllipsis('.otherNews #news5 h2',4,15);
                textEllipsis('#newsMb2 h2',0,15);
            }
        }
```

Call `RWDtextEllipsis()` in `NewsSlideRule()` and the out of `NewsSlideRule()`, but it's broken.

What's wrong with it?

Is there any advice to simplify my code?

Comment: It's not clear how the 3 functions you mention are called.  Why is `NewsSlideRule` declared in the `success` handler, but never used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `.otherNews` calls, there's only actually one argument that's different in all of those - the last one. Set a variable corresponding to that last argument according to each condition, and then call each function.

First section:

```
const otherNewsLastArg = (() => {
  if (window.innerWidth > 1280) return 30;
  if (window.innerWidth > 980) return 10;
  return 15;
})();

if (otherNewsLastArg !== 10) {
  textEllipsis('.biggestNews .majorNews h2', 0, otherNewsLastArg);
} else {
  textEllipsis('.biggestNews .majorNews h2', 0, 15);
}

textEllipsis('.otherNews #news2 h2', 1, otherNewsLastArg);
textEllipsis('.otherNews #news3 h2', 2, otherNewsLastArg);
textEllipsis('.otherNews #news4 h2', 3, otherNewsLastArg);
textEllipsis('.otherNews #news5 h2', 4, otherNewsLastArg);

if (otherNewsLastArg === 15) textEllipsis('#newsMb2 h2',5,15);
```

It's not clear how you want NewsSlideRule to relate to the above code though.

Answer (score 0):

Although the definition of "simplify" is somewhat personal, this is an option on how to make the function looks simpler

```
function RWDtextEllipsis(){
    radius = 0;
    if (window.innerWidth > 980) {
        if(window.innerWidth > 1280) {
            radius = 30;
        } else {
            radius = 10;
        }
        textEllipsis('.biggestNews .majorNews h2',0,15);
    } else {
        radius = 15;
        textEllipsis('#newsMb1 h2',0,15);
        textEllipsis('#newsMb2 h2',0,15);
    }

    // Those repeat on every condition, so put it outside the conditions
    textEllipsis('.otherNews #news2 h2', 1, radius); 
    textEllipsis('.otherNews #news3 h2', 2, radius); 
    textEllipsis('.otherNews #news4 h2', 3, radius); 
    textEllipsis('.otherNews #news5 h2', 4, radius);
    // Which could be further "simplified" to:
    //for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    //    textEllipsis('.otherNews #news2 h2', i, radius); 
    //}
}
```

If you are looking for full code optimization, you should check the [Google Closure](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/)